# How does the CSS background-position property work in this example?

Tags: css

In this example I know the first two values, it's an X Y value and it position the element in the top left.

What does the second set of values do, how does it work?

```css
background-position: 0 0, 25px 25px;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `background-position` value can have multiple comma separated values (just like your example). It is used in situations when you also have multiple background-images defined, these are also comma separated values.

Example of multiple background images:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(background-1.jpg), url(background-2.jpg);
}
```

Combined with multiple background-positions, it will look like below. Each `background-position` definition will match its equivalent inside the `background-image` list.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(background-1.jpg), url(background-2.jpg);
  background-position: 0 0, 25px 25px;
}
```

Read more about [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) and [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) at MDN.

Comment: What does it do here please

Comment: background: radial-gradient(white 15%, transparent 15.1%), rgb(240, 58, 58);
 background-position: 0 0, 25px 25px;

Comment: It will do nothing, because the second background is just defined as a color. See [also this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hu9r4tk1/)